# Stripping byte order mark from zip stream in ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, encoding, inputstream

I know that `File` supposedly takes `encoding: 'bom|utf-8'` but afaict there's no equivalent for streams. My server is getting a zip file containing one csv that has the bom. It seems silly to save the csv as a file vs just using `CSV.new(Zip::InputStream::open(zip_file).get_next_entry.get_input_stream)`, but afaict none of those can detect and strip the byte order mark (bom) and `CSV` fails trying to parse the header if the bom is there.

I see that `CSV.new` takes `encoding` as an option, but, in 2.3.0 at least, it doesn't recognize `bom` (`ArgumentError: unknown encoding name - bom`)

Comment: It should be `"BOM|UTF-8"` not just `"bom"`.

Comment: I, of course, tried that and all the different permutations.

Comment: Fetching `Encoding.name_list` shows no encodings with any similarity to `bom` case invariant or substring. I'd be curious where the `BOM` encoding originates.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can rewind streams, the answer is to get the first chars, see if they're the bom, if they are, consume them; otherwise, rewind the stream.

```
BYTE_ORDER_MARKS_LENGTHS =
  {"\xEF".bytes.first => 2, "\xFE".bytes.first => 1, "\xFF".bytes.first => 1}
# checks if input_stream starts with a byte order mark and if so skips over it
def skip_bom(input_stream)
  entry = BYTE_ORDER_MARKS_LENGTHS[input_stream.read(1).bytes.first]
  if entry
    input_stream.read(entry)
  else
    input_stream.rewind
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like handling the BOM is implemented in `IO` - maybe you can wrap your zip stream around an `IO` object?

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-c-new-label-Open+Mode

Comment: Thanks! Alas, `IO#new` doesn't accept `Zip::InputStream` as a fd, but that at least explains where `BOM` is defined!
`> io = IO.new(stream, 'r:BOM|UTF-8')
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Zip::InputStream into Integer`

Comment: How about passing the IO into zip stream? basically you want to run it through IO first to handle the encoding and then pass it into the zip stream to unzip, and last but not least read it with the CSV library - `CSV.new(Zip::InputStream::open(IO.open(zip_file, 'r:BOM|UTF-8')).get_next_entry.get_input_stream)`

Comment: I believe that the zip file does not have the bom but the file(s) within the zip do; so, that won't work and may actually get false alarms.

Comment: So in that case you'd wrap the stream from the zip in another IO stream maybe?
`stream_with_bom = Zip::InputStream::open(zip_file).get_next_entry.get_input_stream` then `CSV.new IO.open(stream_with_bom, 'r:BOM|UTF-8')`

Comment: If you can upload an example file I could try to actually run the code

Answer (score 0):

My situation was similar, but I also needed to remove extra double-quotes:

```
Zip::File.open(zipfolder) do |zipfile|
  zipfile.each do |zip_entry|
    zip_entry.get_input_stream.each_line do |line|
      line_without_bom_or_quotes = line.force_encoding('UTF-8').gsub('"', '')
      row = CSV.parse_line(line_without_bom_or_quotes)
      puts "DETAIL: #{row.inspect}"
    end
  end
end
```